# Attempting to use Boost Asio to create a remote server-client

Tags: client-server, boost-asio

I want to access a set of values/data from an application running on Windows. I am very new to all of this(with basic programming experience) so right now I found out that using Boost Asio should help me. I looked at the tutorials on the website but they weren't helpful because - I had a hard time understanding the code and difficulty to visualize what it actually does.

What I basically am "supposed" to do -

- Write a "server" program on the Windows machine which gets the data from the application (although I am still unclear as to ***how*** I get that data in the first place, so my problem seems mostly redundant.)
- Write a "client" program on a separate machine running Ubuntu. The client program gets the data from the server and (for now) displays those values. These values are basically a set of positions and rotations (more details aren't really important here I think) and they have to be displayed.

I looked at the examples given [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) but there's no description (proper) or explanation as what they actually do (like I said, I am quite new so some external help is required for me to properly understand all of this)

What I wrote above might not be the best way to do this obviously, and if anyone can suggest some easier/less complicated way then I will appreciate that too and also look into that further.

I have a strong feeling this question will get closed because it might not meet the "regulations", but can anyone please explain/help me out how I can go about this?

Comment: Try to better specify what do you exactly want to do. Server/client is quite unclear.

Comment: @WELLCZECH - I have edited it. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend starting with the [the basics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11602124/1053968).  If you could post areas of the code that you had a difficult time understanding and visualizing, we could provide clarification as to what it does.

Comment: @TannerSansbury - Thank you. I will look into it and edit my query/start a new post once I get into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do making a full-blown application server might be overkill.
If this "set of values/data from an application running on Windows" can be put in a file, you could share its directory using FTP or SMB or HTTP or ... etc etc.

On the linux side you could then mount the directory and use the file as if it were a local file.

You don't need any programming skills for this.

---

If you need a more on-demand real-time approach, you could use a webserver on the Windows machine. If you request the page (the same as requesting a webpage) it can run a script (even start the application) to build a textfile or JSON/XML string with the data and send it back.

This is webservers 101, plenty of tutorials for it. The programmer does not have to worry about stuff like sockets: it is abstracted away.

---

To better answer your question about how to get the data from the Windows application we need to know more about the application.

---

About Boost::asio: IMHO the way to view it is as a wrapper for networking with optional features for event-driven programming. Anyone who knows basic programming can learn it, but it's not easy to start with and will take some time.